# How to efficiently enumerate AWS S3 keyspace

Tags: python, algorithm, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

I'm building an application that needs to list a large amount of objects stored in AWS S3 (let's say 500M to 1 billion objects). Listing objects directly through pagination will take weeks. I'd like to parallelize listing, but to do this efficiently I need to map what is basically an unknown keyspace.

For more background, AWS allows you to provide Prefixes and Delimeters as part of the ListBuckets operation. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html

So, it looks like I need an algorithm that can enumerate an unknown S3 keyspace (prefix-space?) and attempt to group the discovered prefixes into approximately [X] equally sized buckets that can be parallelized for even sampling and speed to list.

High level pseudocode:

1. Execute parallel searches with a prefix of [0-9a-z] combinations of N (let's say 3) letters and a max-keys size of 1k.
2. For any searches that returned with more than max-keys keys (we don't know exact size), execute subsequent GETs with a prefix of [discovered prefix]+[0-9a-z]. If search returned with between 1-999 keys, add to separate bucket list
3. Once we are comfortable that we have as even of distribution of keys (perhaps after N recursive steps) as possible, task workers to start listing their own buckets

Challenges:

- Build an even sampling distribution to send to the workers to list.
- Need to minimize chance that one worker needs to do all the work.
- What if all prefixes start with "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"? =)

The goal would be to programmatically discover and group prefixes to enable even sampling and parallelization for listing of an unknown prefix structure. Any ideas on algorithms, links, examples would be much appreciated!

Comment: The available interface makes this tricky.  Faced with a similar situation, in true "sqlbot" form, my solution to object listing iteration was to store the keys and object versions in a relational database (MariaDB in RDS), preloaded by iterating the listings once, and subsequently maintained using S3 event notifications with Lambda.  I also store (and index) all the object metadata, so it's also queryable, and have a stored procedure that emulates listing objects by prefix (and supports the concept of "commom prefixes" like the List Objects API) but the listing returned is unbounded.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Agreed that building a metadata DB is a good way to go for fast accesses after enumerating all objects. I'm trying to do something slightly different- find a way to parallelize initial listing of all objects, with somewhat even sampling across unknown prefixes and large stores. This is for the scenario with with 500M+ objects which would take prohibitively long to list sequentially

Comment: How much time do you have, theoretically, to iterate these objects?  What's a target completion time?  You will need to send a minimum of 500,000 requests to list 500M objects and buckets do have a finite capacity for handling List Objects requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a tool that will recursively analyze S3 keyspace with a producer/consumer system, such that every newly discovered prefix is enumerated in a different thread. That's the most efficient approach that I can find.

It would be nice if there was a way to retrieve objects by ETag, but then, it would also be nice if etags were unique within a bucket, and they aren't.

Here is the code:

```
def search_objects(bucket, prefix=None, *, name, delimiter='/', limit=None, searchFoundPrefixes=True, threads=20):
    """Search for occurences of a name. Returns a list of all found keys as dictionaries.
    @param bucket - the bucket to search
    @param prefix - the prefix to start with
    @param name   - the name being searched for
    @param delimiter - the delimiter that separates names
    @param limit  - the maximum number of names keys to return
    @param searchFoundPrefixes - If true, do not search for prefixes below where name is found.
    @param threads - the number of Python threds to use. Note that this is all in the same process.
    """

    import queue
    import threading

    if limit is None:
        limit = sys.maxsize  # should be big enough
    ret = []

    def worker():
        while True:
            prefix = q.get()
            if prefix is None:
                break
            found_prefixes = []
            found_names = 0
            for obj in list_objects(bucket, prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter):
                if _Prefix in obj:
                    found_prefixes.append(obj[_Prefix])
                if (_Key in obj) and obj[_Key].split(delimiter)[-1] == name:
                    if len(ret) < limit:
                        ret.append(obj)
                if len(ret) > limit:
                    break
            if found_names == 0 or searchFoundPrefixes:
                if len(ret) < limit:
                    for lp in found_prefixes:
                        q.put(lp)
            q.task_done()

    q = queue.Queue()
    thread_pool = []
    for i in range(threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        t.start()
        thread_pool.append(t)
    q.put(prefix)

    # block until all tasks are done
    q.join()

    # stop workers
    for i in range(threads):
        q.put(None)
    for t in thread_pool:
        t.join()
    return ret
```